# Blob.generate_signed_url() failing to AttributeError

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-python

So I'm trying to produce temporary globally readable URLs for my Google Cloud Storage objects using the `google-cloud-storage` Python library (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html) - more specifically the Blob.generate_signed_url() method. I doing this from within a Compute Engine instance in a command line Python script. And I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'oauth2cl
ient.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials'> just contains a token. see https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs
.io/en/latest/core/auth.html?highlight=authentication#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.
```

I am aware that there are issues with doing this from within GCE (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/issues/50) but I have created a new Service Account credentials following the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program and my key.json file most certainly includes a private key. Still I am seeing that error.

This is my code:

```
keyfile = "/path/to/my/key.json"
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(keyfile)
expiration = timedelta(3) # valid for 3 days
url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration, method="GET",
                               credentials=credentials)
```

I've read through the issue tracker here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen and nothing related jumps out so I am assuming this should work. Cannot see what's going wrong here.

Comment: I am currently hunting the solution for this, as well, because I need a way to sign upload URLs without physical access to a key file. I got this working when a service account key (.json) is configured to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, but, perhaps like you, I want my code to operate with the default credentials implicit to instances on GCP. Did you solve it?

Comment: When connecting local machine to storage, we can use credentials from json. But when reading file on app engine from storage- i dont know how to get credentials. docs say default service account should just work fine. But I always get error ' need private key to sign'

Answer (score 19):

I was having the same issue. Ended up fixing it by starting the storage client directly from the service account json.

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('path_to_service_account_key.json')
```

I know I'm late to the party but hopefully this helps!

Comment: You saved my life! For anyone else reading this in the future, I found this only applied to creation of v2 signed URLs, when using v4 this did not apply

Comment: Doesn't work; that's what I did to get the error in the first place.

Comment: doesn't match with workload identity enabled

Comment: What if I dont want to save sv account key in GIT. is there a way ?

Comment: worked in v4 for me

Comment: This worked in v4 for me too. Also if you already have the service account as a dictionary loaded, you can use `from_service_account_info`

Answer (score 13):

Currently, it's not possible to use `blob.generate_signed_url` without explicitly referencing credentials. (Source: [Class Blob - generate_signed_url](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_generate_signed_url)) However, you can do a workaround, as seen [here](https://gist.github.com/jezhumble/91051485db4462add82045ef9ac2a0ec), which consists of:

```py
signing_credentials = compute_engine.IDTokenCredentials(
    auth_request,
    "",
    service_account_email=credentials.service_account_email
)
signed_url = signed_blob_path.generate_signed_url(
    expires_at_ms,
    credentials=signing_credentials,
    version="v4"
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to put the `service_account_email` in the environment, as `credentials.service_account_email` was coming back as _default_ (I think)

Comment: This code works tho afterwards I had to follow this to get the right permissions in google cloud https://stackoverflow.com/a/62327597/494560

Comment: How do I get this "auth_request" variable?

Answer (score 4):

A much complete snippet for those asking where other elements come from. cc @AlbertoVitoriano

```py
    from google.auth.transport import requests
    from google.auth import default, compute_engine
    
    credentials, _ = default()
    
    # then within your abstraction
    auth_request = requests.Request()
    credentials.refresh(auth_request)
    
    signing_credentials = compute_engine.IDTokenCredentials(
        auth_request,
        "",
        service_account_email=credentials.service_account_email
    )
    signed_url = signed_blob_path.generate_signed_url(
        expires_at_ms,
        credentials=signing_credentials,
        version="v4"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run GCloud SDK outside of GCP using Application Default Credentials (as you do with your user account) and make it work as a Service Account by "impersonating the SA".
Notice, though, that for this to work you need to have the "Service Account Token Creator" role, which will allow you to create tokens "impersonating" another account (the Service Account).

When you have the permission, run the `gcloud auth` ADC login procedure, but "upgrading" you ADC credentials to an impersonated SA, like this:

```
$ gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=[your-service-account-id]@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

After that, your local ADC credentials are tied to the said SA. Keep in mind that audit trails for operations performed with this SA keep record of who requested the impersonation (ie. you).
You can check it by comparing your current ADC credentials file with the newly generated above.

This way, your code will run outside GCP exactly the same than on GCP, without any conditional code and without having to juggle with JSON credentials, which is highly discouraged by Google.