# Unable to assign iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

TLDR; I'm having trouble assigning an IAM permission to a service account.

I'm building a test that involves minting custom tokens with firebase Auth. When I hit:

```
  const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken('test', {
    isAdmin: true,
  })
```

the following error is thrown

```
Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform
this operation on service account 
projects/-/serviceAccounts/dashboard@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.;
Please refer to 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
for more details on how to use and troubleshoot this feature
```

In the [referenced documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) it says to add the **Service Account Token Creator** role to the service account. I have added that role (as well as tried Service Account Admin to no avail.
[image: Image verifying permissions]

I can verify that my permissions seem to be correctly set, when I run 
`gcloud projects get-iam-policy project` I can see my service account attached to the desired role

```
- members:
  - serviceAccount:dashboard@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

However if I look at that specific service account, it seems to show up empty which would fall in line with my error:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy dashboard@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
etag: ACAB
```

- **Why would those two commands & cloud console show differing information?**

I assume that whatever is causing my service account permissions to show up blank is the culprit, but I'm not sure where to debug further. It seems to me the only difference is one command is called with a project in it, but I initialize my firebase app with the project id, and have verified it with `(firebase-admin).apps[0].options` so it seems like a dead end.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `sign` feature of a service account requires the `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob` permission. This permission is included in the Service Account Token role `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`

You can assign this role at the "project" level or at the "service account" level. This is why you see different results. Assigning roles at the project level affects permissions for all service accounts. Assigning roles at the service account only affects that service account.

The key to your problem is that the caller does not have this role on service account `dashboard@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. You have given the service account permission and NOT the caller. Look into your code for the service account that you used to setup the Firebase SDK.

Another option is to grant the role to `{YOUR_PROJECT_NAME}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` (1st gen) or `{RANDOM_NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` (2nd gen) but that grants permission to use any service account.

A service account is both an identity and a resource. You need permission for the resource. That permission can be granted via a service account's IAM policy or via the project's IAM policy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I'm a little confused though, is the supplied service account to `initializeApp` not the service account used by the code? I am using the same service account, and see it listed when I look at the initialized apps options.  `admin.initializeApp({
  projectId:project,
  serviceAccountId: dashboard@appspot.gserviceaccount.com',
});`

Comment: Edit your question with your code. Include enough to see everything from initialization to usage of the service account

Comment: Where is your code running (Compute Engine, App Engine, your desktop)? Your initialization code will only work with a Google service as it relies upon ADC. Outside of Google, you will need to use a service account JSON key file to initialize Firebase.

Comment: My code is running on my desktop. I've used `gcloud auth application default` with my user account so this initialization looks similar to how I initialize storage, pubsub, etc. Does firebase admin have different restrictions than those other SDKs?

Comment: What is the user id (gcloud auth list). Verify that the user id has the permissions mentioned above.

Comment: Ahh, that was it! My user account is an owner for the project and I assumed that would include all permissions but apparently not. Thank you for your help!

Comment: how to assign that role on itself at service account level?

Answer (score 25):

Firebase mentions about this error on its docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#failed_to_determine_service_account

You must initialize your app correctly through a JSON config file.

A simple fix would be:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=PROJECT_NAME
2. Edit your default service account.
3. Add the role Service Account Token Creator

In a few minutes your project will be able to create signed tokens.

Comment: Is there a way to do this only for specific email addresses?

Answer (score 7):

If you still get `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob required` error message even after following what others have said and you are using Firebase Cloud Functions, here are a few things you need to keep in mind.

- If you are running "Firebase Local Emulator" or non-Google environment (i.e. not using Google Cloud), then your best option is to use [service account JSON file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk_in_non-google_environments). Note that in this case, the service account defined in the JSON file (that would be `firebase-adminsdk-*****@PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com` in my case) doesn't need to have `Service Account Token Creator` role, because JSON file itself contains the private key. Not a terribly secure way to handle things, but there aren't many other options.
- Firebase Cloud Functions come in 2 different flavors: [1st gen and 2nd gen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/version-comparison). 1st gen's service account is typically `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`, and 2nd gen is `RANDOM-NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. If you are using 2nd gen Cloud Function, you need to give `Service Account Token Creator` to the 2nd gen's service account. You can find it in "Google Cloud Console -> Your Project -> Serverless (in left pane) -> Cloud Functions -> Select function -> Details (2nd tab) -> Look for `Service account`".

Comment: I just upgraded to 2nd gen cloud functions and this was exactly my problem. To add the `Service Account Token Creator` role to my 2nd gen cloud function's service accounts I went to [my project's IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) and found the `${rand()}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` service account, then clicked the `Edit Principal` pencil icon on the right, then `ADD ANOTHER ROLE`, then searched for `Service Account Token Creator` and hit `Save`. I had to wait a few minutes for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to accomplish this task within a Firebase Cloud function using .onCall(), please follow the steps outlined below:

```py
from firebase_admin import storage
from google.auth import compute_engine
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from datetime import timedelta

def your_function(parameter):
    # Create an authentication request
    auth_request = Request()

    # Get your IDTokenCredentials
    signing_credentials = compute_engine.IDTokenCredentials(
        auth_request,
        "",
        service_account_email='<ADD YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT MAIL(Principal)>'
    )

    # Get your storage bucket
    data_bucket = storage.bucket('<YOUR BUCKET>')
    
    # Generate a signed URL for your bucket
    blob = data_bucket.blob(parameter)
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        expiration=timedelta(days=7),
        credentials=signing_credentials, 
        version="v4"
    )
    
    return url
```

Remember to replace '<ADD YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT MAIL(Principal)>' and '' with your actual service account email and bucket name, respectively.